# Check if its a table inside a td

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Supposed I have a HTML like this:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><br>
    <blockquote>
      <p align="center"><br>Test<br></p>
      <p align="center"><b>Test2</b></p><b>
      </b>
      <p>Test 3</p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr valign="top">
            <td>Header1</td>
            <td>Header2</td>
            <td>Header3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr valign="top">
            <td>val1</td>
            <td>val2</td>
            <td>val3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p align="justify">test 5</p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr align="center">
            <td>test z</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p align="justify">ee</p>
      <p>qq</p>
      <p>yy</p>
    </blockquote>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to check if its a table, if its not print its text, the output should be like this:

```
Test
Test2

Test 3
test 5

ee
qq
yy
```

This is the code that i have right now:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td')
for child in td.find_all(recursive=False):
    if child.name != 'table':
        print(child.text)
```

However it still gives me the text inside the table:

```
Test
Test2

Test 3

Header1
Header2
Header3

val1
val2
val3

test 5
test z

ee
qq
yy
```

I dont want to strip the table inside the TD I I have something to do with that. Thanks

Comment: Maybe somebody smarter can do it, but I can't figure out how to do that w/ beautifulsoup. It is, however, fairly easy with lxml, if available.

Answer (score 0):

you want to exclude `table` element, so you can first delete that element from the `td` object and then print all content of `td` element.
you also have to make `recursive=True` in order to delete `table` element from `td`

here is the code which works:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td')
for child in td.find_all(recursive=True):
    if child.name == 'table':
      child.decompose()
print(td.text)
```

and there will be a space between `Test 3` and `test 5`
output:

```
Test
Test2

Test 3

test 5

ee
qq
yy
```